# How to access a video thumbnail saved using paperclip and paperclip-av-transcoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using paperclip and paperclip-av-transcoder to save a video and create thumbnail for it while saving. Paperclip model as follows.

```
class NewsAssets::Video < NewsAssets::Base

  has_attached_file :attachment,:styles => {
    :thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10 },:medium => {:geometry => "640x480", :format => 'mp4' }
    }, :processors => [:transcoder],
    :path => (Rails.env.development? ? "#{Rails.root}/public/sys_path/:styles/:basename.:extension" : "public/sys_path/:styles/:basename.:extension"),
    :url => (Rails.env.development? ? "/sys_path/:styles/:basename.:extension" : ':s3_alias_url'),
    :storage => (Rails.env.development? ? :filesystem : :s3),
    :s3_permissions => 'public_read'
end
```

after saving the video thumbnail is creating inside a folder as a jpg image.

```
public/sys_path/thumbs/file.jpg
```

But not able to retrieve it. I am using rails-4. Is there any papercrip way or method to retrieve the thumb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
   <%@videos.each do |v|
      <p><%= image_tag(v.vid.url(:thumb)) %></p>
    <% end %>
```

whereas my model has

```
has_attached_file :vid, :styles => {
    :mp4 => { :format => 'mp4', :convert_options => { :output => { :vcodec => 'libx264' } } } ,
    :thumb => { :geometry => "200x200#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10 }
  }, :processors => [:ffmpeg]
```